# Problema Respuesta mensaje formulario php

Tags: php, html, css3, formularios

Tengo un formulario que me responde con un mensaje de bienvenida, pero ese mensaje de bienvenida no me aplica ningún estilo y no sé cómo ponerlo ni dónde está el fallo. Este es mi código:

```
 if(mail($emailA,$headers,$contenido)) {
    $mensajeExito = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Mensaje enviado con éxito</strong>, pronto nos pondremos en contacto.</div>';
 }
 else {
```

Esto sería el formulario PHP y luego en mi hoja de estilos CSS tengo estos estilos para que se apliquen:

```
.alert {
    padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}   

.alert-success {
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d0e9c6;
    color: #3c763d;
}
```

¿Donde estaría el error? ¿Por qué no me lee ningún estilo lo ponga como lo ponga? He probado también poniendo /" pero el resultado es el mismo sin estilos.

La respuesta del `echo` la tengo aquí imprimida:

```
   <div id="error"><? echo $error.$mensajeExito; ?></div>
```

que se me olvidó ponerlo antes. Esto está dentro del formulario para que me salga ahí la respuesta del mensaje.

Comment: No estas imprimiendo el mensaje

Comment: Deberías incluir más código PHP (el `if...else` completo) y a ser posible el código HTML y CSS generado también. Además, sería bueno que explicaras mejor cómo falla, ¿no se le pone ningún estilo? ¿O se le pone el estilo de error pero no el de éxito? ¿qué mensaje se lee cuando el formulario se envía correctamente? ¿cuáles son los estilos de `.error`? Lo que pones en la pregunta parece correcto a simple vista, por lo que hace falta más información para saber qué es lo que realmente está fallando.

Comment: Entiendo que el mensaje si que se visualiza pero sin los estilos, no?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la condicion del if sea correcta te falta imprimir el valor:

```
if(mail($emailA,$headers,$contenido)) {
        $mensajeExito = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Mensaje enviado con éxito</strong>, pronto nos pondremos en contacto.</div>';
        echo mensajeExito;
     }
     else {
        echo "<p>¡Error!</p>";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola te conviene imprimir el priminer mensaje de la misma forma que imprimis el segundo:

`if (true) {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Mensaje enviado con éxito</strong>, pronto nos pondremos en contacto.</div> ';
    } else{
      echo '<p>¡Error!</p>';
    }`

Saludos!